# Receiving multiple byte arrays from socket

Tags: java, android, arrays, sockets, bitmap

I'm currently working on a remote desktop app. The server part runs on Android device and the client one on PC/Raspberry PI. I've encountered a problem with receiving my bitmaps (screenshots from Android, send as byte arrays). 
The **Android Server** code goes like this:

```
//os = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());   
   public void run() {
            while(true){
            try {

                View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                int quality = 100;

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                if(byteArray.length>0) {

                    os.writeInt(byteArray.length);

                    os.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                    os.flush();
                    }                   
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}}
```

And the **Receiver App** on PC like this:

```
//ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
public void run() {
         while(true){

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int size = ois.readInt();
            System.out.println(size);
            byte[] data = new byte[size];
            int length = 0;


            while ((length = ois.read(data,0,size)) != -1) {
                out.write(data, 0, size);
                out.flush();
            }
            byte[] bytePicture = out.toByteArray();
            out.close();

            BufferedImage buffImage = byteArrayToImage(bytePicture);

            ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(buffImage);

            l.setIcon(imgIcon);
            } catch (IOException e) {
        }}}
```

**byteArrayToImage**

```
public static BufferedImage byteArrayToImage(byte[] bytes) {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return bufferedImage;
    }
```

The problem is that in the **receiver app** I get Java OutOfMemoryException because I cannot differ between incoming screenshots. I really cannot figure out how to read exactly the size of a bitmap (as byte array) then display it and read another and another one. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when reading you have to read exactly `size` bytes,  you are not doing that and thus can cross a message boundary, btw you can use google's protocol buffers to make your life easier

Comment: ' out.write(data, 0, size);'. That should be  out.write(data, 0, length);. And you should add a variable int nreceived = 0; And in the loop add the length to it. Do not ask to read size bytes but size-nreceived. Check if nreceived becomes equal to size.

Comment: @greenapps thank you very much :)